# Como Pegar o menor valor de uma série de inputs

Tags: python, lógica

o usuario digita um código e a quantidade desejada, esse código refere-se a algum valor da lista e então o valor da lista é multiplicado pela quantidade. dessa multiplicação quero o valor mais caro (ja consegui) e o mais barato, esse ultimo não consegui pois fazer 'barato = 0' ja tornaria o menor valor possível, empaquei aqui.

```
codigos = [4.20, 7.30, 8.50, 9.20, 10.30, 8.30]
val_tot = frete = caro = 0
barato  = ?

while True:
menu = int(input('[1] Adicionar pedido \n[-1] finalizar programa: '))
if menu == -1:
    break
elif menu == 1:
 input('Digite o CPF: ')
 cod = int(input('Digite o código do produto: '))
 qtd = int(input(' Quatidade: '))
 frete += 5
 if cod == 100:
     val_tot += codigos[0] * qtd
     if codigos[0] * qtd > caro:
         caro = codigos[0] * qtd
     elif codigos[0] * qtd < barato:
         barato = (codigos[0] * qtd)
 elif cod == 101:
     val_tot += codigos[1] * qtd
     if codigos[1] * qtd > caro:
         caro = codigos[1] * qtd
     elif codigos[1] * qtd < barato:
         barato = (codigos[1] * qtd)
 elif cod == 102:
     val_tot += codigos[2] * qtd
     if codigos[2] * qtd > caro:
         caro = codigos[2] * qtd
     elif codigos[2] * qtd < barato:
         barato = (codigos[2] * qtd)
elif cod == 103:
    val_tot += codigos[3] * qtd
    if codigos[3] * qtd > caro:
        caro = codigos[3] * qtd
    elif codigos[3] * qtd < barato:
        barato = (codigos[3] * qtd)
elif cod == 104:
    val_tot += codigos[4] * qtd
    if codigos[4] * qtd > caro:
        caro = codigos[4] * qtd
    elif codigos[4] * qtd < barato:
        barato = (codigos[4] * qtd)
elif cod == 105:
    val_tot += codigos[5] * qtd
    if codigos[5] * qtd > caro:
        caro = codigos[5] * qtd
    elif codigos[5] * qtd < barato:
        barato = (codigos[5] * qtd)
print('Pedido mais caro: {}' .format(caro))
print('Pedido mais barato: {}' .format(barato))
print('Valor total arrecadado pelo motoboy: {}'.format(frete * 0.6))
print ('Valor arrecadado pela lanchonete: {}'.format(val_tot + (frete * 0.4)))
```

Comment: Você pode armazenar numa variável o valor mais barato e ir comparando. Se for menor você atualiza esse valor.

Comment: Se iniciar com `barato = 999999` ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria um dicionário `produto` onde a chave é o código e o valor é o preço.

A cada passagem no `while` eu adicionaria um `pedido` em uma lista sempre que o usuário responder `s`.

Quando a resposta for `n` as funções `min` e `max` retornam o pedido mais "barato" e o mais "caro".

Note que não é feito nenhum tipo de validação. Então digite os códigos corretos para testar senão vai dar problema. Códigos válidos: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 e 60

```
produto = {10:4.20, 20:7.30, 30:8.50, 40:9.20, 50:10.30, 60:8.30}

pedido = []

continuar = 's' 

while continuar == 's':    

    cod = int(input('Digite o código do produto: '))

    qtd = int(input(' Quatidade: '))

    pedido.append(produto.get(cod) * float(qtd))

    print(pedido)

    continuar = input("Deseja continuar? 's' ou 'n' ")

    if continuar == 'n':        
        print('\nPedido mais caro: {}' .format(max(pedido)))
        print('Pedido mais barato: {}' .format(min(pedido)))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Inicie a variável `barato` com `None`

```
barato = None
```

E em todas as linhas em que você verifica se o valor é o mais barato, troque o `elif` for `if` e adicione o teste `barato is None or ...`

Ou seja, onde tinha isso:

```
elif codigos[0] * qtd < barato:
     barato = (codigos[0] * qtd)
```

Vai virar isso:

```
if barato is None or codigos[0] * qtd < barato:
    barato = (codigos[0] * qtd)
```

Assim por diante para todos os códigos.